# Change data type of values in DataFrames.jl table

Tags: dataframe, type-conversion, julia, dataframes.jl

I need to change the data type of a value (or column-wise if needed be) within a DataFrame.jl object. From `String` to `Int` specifically. Not encountering any luck even with the minimal example:

```
using DataFrames
df=DataFrame(x=["1","2","3"])
df.x[1]=parse(Int,df.x[1]) # Returns error!
```

Why? What's a workaround?

Comment: do you want to change a single value or the whole column?

Comment: If you want to change the whole column, using broadcasting: `df.x=parse.(Int,df.x)` is a simpe solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the data frame column is still set to be of type `String` so that you cannot assign a value of type `Int` to it. You would have to change the type of the whole column. Something like below should work:

```
using DataFrames
df=DataFrame(x=["1","2","3"])
select(df, :x => ByRow(x -> parse(Int, x)) => :x)
```

Answer (score 1):

A better option  (faster, less allocations) would be just:

```
using DataFrames
df=DataFrame(x=["1","2","3"])
df.x .= parse.(Int, df.x)
```